# How can I play all of mp3s in a folder continously with sox

Tags: linux, mp3, sox

I use sox for play audio in my computer. I love it. But I don't know how to repeat all of my mp3s in a folder.

```
play -R *.mp3
```

and

```
play repeat 10 *.mp3
```

not works. After end of sequence it exited. 
Okay, I can write a script to repeat infinitly, but if be an simplier way, I want to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-R` flag for `sox` probably doesn't do what you think it does, so omit it unless you are sure you need it.

What you might want is this infinite loop

```
while true; do play *.mp3; done
```

The `true` keyword, which by definition returns a "true" value for the `while` loop, can replaced with the shorter `:`, which also returns a "true" value by virtue of it doing nothing and not failing while doing so

```
while :; do play *.mp3; done
```